# Backlink question - google viewer

Tags: google, backlinks, iframe, pdf

I have documents (.pdfs) that I'm planning to post on a site using the google docs viewer. I think others may wish to embed the same documents on their sites since the documents will be updated, timely, and newsworthy. I'm providing an easy embed code for people to copy and paste (like Scribd does).

The embed code looks something like this:

```
<iframe src = "http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.mysite.com/downloads/theDocument.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:850px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

How would Google 'crawl' this code if its posted on another site? Would google credit me a backlink from another site even though my site url is sort of buried in the code above? Anybody have experience with this?

I could always just use an iframe or embed code directly to the document and skip the google docs viewer, but I figure people will find it more trustworthy and it's certain to fit all browsers and devices. Let me know if you have a better alternative.

Comment: Please delete [the SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563521/using-google-docs-viewer). Don't cross-post topics; if something belongs on another site, request it be migrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not count as backlink, however it is thought that mentions counts, even if only marginally in most cases.

An option could be adding a link to your website taking credit for the document in the embedding code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that Google does not count it as a link from the other site at all ... neither the link embedded in the iframed page, nor the call from the other site to bring up the iframe.